# jQuery dynamic content with images not loading/rendering properly in IE8/9

Tags: jquery

I have created a site with an online store.  There are different categories of products.  I am displaying these categories using jQuery tabs.  Each category tab lists the products under that category.  I am creating the category tabs and the content dynamically using jQuery.  I am also using jQuery NailThumb to generate the thumbnails on the fly.  The URL is:

http://www.thekclonghorns.com/TeamStore/Store.aspx

The page renders properly on all browsers except IE8 and IE9.  After I cycle through all the tabs, then it shows up fine in IE8 and IE9.

The code to display the Store is as below.  Any ideas why this does not render properly in IE?

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    setupPage();

});

function setupPage() {
    showProgress();
    clearProducts();

    setupCategories();
}

function setupCategories() {
    loadingCount++;

    GetCategories([], true,
    {
        successCallback: function (data) {
            if ((data) && (data != null) && (data.length > 0)) {
                setupProducts(data);
            }

            data = null;
        },
        errorCallback: function (httpRequest, status, error, functionName) {
            httpRequest = null;
            status = null;
            error = null;
            functionName = null;
        },
        completeCallback: function () {
            loadingCount--;
            checkLoading();
        }
    });
}

function setupProducts(categories) {
    GetProducts([], true,
    {
        successCallback: function (data) {
            if ((data) && (data != null) && (data.length > 0)) {
                buildCategoryDisplay(categories, data);
            }

            data = null;
        },
        errorCallback: function (httpRequest, status, error, functionName) {
            httpRequest = null;
            status = null;
            error = null;
            functionName = null;
        },
        completeCallback: function () {
            loadingCount--;
            checkLoading();
        }
    });
}

function buildCategoryDisplay(categories, products) {
    var content = [];
    var category;
    var product;
    var totalCols = 4;
    var limit = 0;

    content.push("<div id=\"tabs\">");
    content.push("<ul>");

    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        category = categories[i];
        if (category.IsActive) {
            content.push("<li><a href=\"#tabs-" + category.Id + "\">" + category.Name + "</a></li>");
        }
    }
    content.push("</ul>");

    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        category = categories[i];
        if (category.IsActive) {
            content.push("<div id=\"tabs-" + category.Id + "\">");
            content.push("<h4>" + category.Name + "</h4>");
            //get the list of products for this category and display them with links to details page
            if (products != null && products.length > 0) {
                content.push("<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" rules=\"none\" border=\"0\" class=\"modal_page_form\" style=\"width: 540px; margin: 4px;border-collapse: collapse; margin-bottom: 0px;\">");
                content.push("<tr>");
                for (var j = 0; j < products.length; j++) {                    
                    product = products[j];
                    if (product.Category.Name == category.Name) {
                        limit = limit + 1;
                        content.push("<td><a href=" + pageLocation + "TeamStore/StoreProductDetails.aspx?ProductId=" + product.Id + ">");
                        if (product.HasPhotos) {
                            content.push("<div class=\"nailthumb-container\" href=" + pageLocation + "Uploads/" + product.Photos[0].ImagePath.replace(/ /gi, "%20") + "><img src=" + pageLocation + "Uploads/" + product.Photos[0].ImagePath.replace(/ /gi, "%20") + "></img></div>");
                        }
                        else {
                            content.push("<div class=\"nailthumb-container\" href=" + pageLocation + "Uploads/no-img.jpg><img src=" + pageLocation + "Uploads/no-img.jpg></img></div>");
                        }
                        content.push("<br/><br/><p>" + product.Title + "<br/>$" + product.Cost + "</p>");
                        content.push("</a></td>");
                        if (limit == totalCols) {
                            content.push("</tr><tr>");
                            limit = 0; //reset limit
                        }
                    }
                }
                limit = 0;
                content.push("</tr></table>");
            }

            content.push("</div>");
        }
    }

    content.push("</div>");

    $("#productsContainer").replaceHtml(content.join(""));
    $("#productsContainer").show();
    $(".nailthumb-container").nailthumb({ width: 100, height: 100, fitDirection: 'top left' });

    $("#tabs").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
    $("#tabs li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");

    content = null;
    category = null;
    product = null;
    totalCols = null;
    limit = null;
}


function clearProducts() {
    $("#productsContainer").replaceHtml("").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty answer is that you're forcing the page to load as IE7 standards.

The page loads fine in IE 8/9 so long as it's not in IE7 Standards Document Mode.

Removing the following from the head (or changing it to 8, or whatever the lowest ver is you need for compatibility, assuming you even need to use X-UA-Compatible) should fix things:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />`

As to why it's breaking IE7 Standards Document Mode would be a different question, but technically everything is fine for IE8/9, you're just forcing them to use 7 Standards which **does** break.

Comment: Thanks so much!  That fixed it!  I completely forgot I had added that header in my master file.  Appreciate the help.  :)

Comment: Glad it wasn't a problem for anything else to just do that! Sometimes it's those little things that are SO easy to overlook when you've been staring at the code too long and you need a fresh view to notice it's something else =)